# Can I upload my Garmin Forerunner running track data from my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, hardware-recommendation, gps

I use a Garmin Forerunner 405CX GPS watch to track my running.

At the moment I have to use an ANT+ USB dongle to get the data (GPX) from my watch on to my computer/laptop.

I upload the data to the Endomondo and Runkeeper websites either by way of a Firefox/ActiveX plugin or by manually uploading the GPX file.

I want to remove the laptop from this process so is there a dongle (or similar) that will allow me to perform the same process(es) directly on the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few devices I found that have been recently added to the market

- [Garmin Ant+ adaptor for iPhone](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?pID=103887&ra=true)
- [Wahoo Key for iPhone](http://www.wahoofitness.com/Products/Wahoo-Fitness-Wahoo-Key-for-iPhone.asp)

Both allow you to connect and record in real time exercise data in association with their and other third party apps ([Garmin Fit](https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?pID=104231) and Wahoo have a list [here](http://www.wahoofitness.com/Apps/Apps.asp))

What I have not been able to confirm is whether it will provide upload facility from devices after being out of range as you want.

My assumption is yes it can, since you can get swim watch data entry.

All the products were originally designed for iPhone and I don't see any issue with running them on an ipad

Comment: I presume the app or website I want to upload the data to would need to support input/upload via the app or via iPad Safari though?

Comment: that would entirely depend on the app used.  I suggest you research the apps and the dongles a bit more to ensure that this is a valid answer, but it's a little outside of the Ask Different remit

Comment: I think I'll take a look at the two suggested dongles and maybe post in the Endomondo and Runkeeper forums too. Thanks.